# RecyclerView Sticky Header onClick and scrollbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've made a decoration class to create sticky headers in a recyclerview. I have two problems about that.

1. While listening for the clicks, when a normal item is under the sticky header, clicks for sticky header doesn't work.(The item under it, is clicked.)
2. Since I'm drawing over the sticky headers, they are drawn on to the scrollbar and hide it.

So I'm wondering how can I fix those? Is coding a custom layout manager the only way? I can't think of any other solutions. I'm not even sure a custom layout manager can solve this.

Below you can find my decoration class:

```
package com.done.xrecyclerview.library;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;

public class StickyHeaderDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration
{

private static final boolean D = true;
private static final String TAG = "HeaderDecoration";

private void init()
{
    //Do your initializations here.
}


@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state)
{
    super.onDrawOver(c, parent, state);
    if (parent.getAdapter() != null && parent.getAdapter()
                                             .getItemCount() > 1) //RecylerView's adapter exist and has items.
    {

        View firstView = parent.getChildAt(0); //get the first visible view.
        View secondView = parent.getChildAt(1); //get the second visible view.

        View headerView = getHeaderOf(parent, firstView); //get the first visible view's header.

        if (isHeaderView(parent, secondView)) //if the second view is also a header
        {
            if (secondView.getTop() <= headerView.getHeight())
                c.translate(0,
                        secondView.getTop() - headerView.getHeight()); //translate the canvas
        }

        headerView.draw(c);

        c.save();
        //c.restore();
        c.translate(0, 0);
    }
}

/**
 * Determines whether the given View is a header.
 *
 * @param parent Parent of given view.
 * @param view   View to be checked.
 * @return true if the view is a header, false otherwise
 */
private boolean isHeaderView(RecyclerView parent, View view)
{

    if (parent.getAdapter() instanceof XRecyclerViewAdapter) //check if the adapter of RecyclerView is an instance of our custom adapter.
    {
        int childPosition = parent.getChildPosition(view); //get position of the view in the adapter.
        XRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = (XRecyclerViewAdapter) parent.getAdapter(); //get the adapter itself.
        return adapter.get(childPosition)
                      .getItemType() == XItemTypes.HEADER; //if the item of the position of view is header.
    } else
        return false;
}

/**
 * Checks whether the given position is occupied by a header.
 *
 * @param parent   RecyclerView that contains the given position.
 * @param position Position to be checked.
 * @return true if the position is occupied by a header. false otherwise.
 */
private boolean isHeaderPosition(RecyclerView parent, int position)
{
    XRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = (XRecyclerViewAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
    return adapter.get(position).getItemType() == XItemTypes.HEADER;
}


/**
 * Finds the header of given view.
 *
 * @param parent Parent of the view.
 * @param view   View itself whose header will be found.
 * @return If the given View is already a header, returns that view.
 * If the view doesn't have a header returns null.
 * If the view has a header returns the view's header.
 */
private View getHeaderOf(RecyclerView parent, View view)
{
    if (isHeaderView(parent, view)) //item is already header.
        return view; //return the view.
    else //item is child. Find it's header.
    {
        int position = parent.getChildPosition(view); //get the position of given child item in adapter.
        //Log.i(TAG, "position = " + position);
        XRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = (XRecyclerViewAdapter) parent.getAdapter(); //get the adapter.
        for (int i = position; i >= 0; i--) //iterate backwards from the position of given child item.
        {
            if (isHeaderPosition(parent, i)) //if the iterated position is occupied by a header
            {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = adapter.onCreateViewHolder(parent,
                        XRecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_HEADER); //create its viewholder.
                adapter.onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, i); //bind its viewholder.

                View header = viewHolder.itemView; //get that header view to set LayoutParams.

                if (header.getLayoutParams() == null) //if the LayoutParams null, initiate it.
                {
                    header.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                }

                int widthSpec;
                int heightSpec;

                widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getWidth(),
                        View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.getHeight(),
                        View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

                int childWidth = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                        parent.getPaddingLeft() + parent.getPaddingRight(),
                        header.getLayoutParams().width);
                int childHeight = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                        parent.getPaddingTop() + parent.getPaddingBottom(),
                        header.getLayoutParams().height);
                header.measure(childWidth, childHeight);
                header.layout(0, 0, header.getMeasuredWidth(), header.getMeasuredHeight());

                return header;

            }
        }

    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: maybe you can grab some info from here? https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM

Comment: Oh, i see this post is 6 months old already.. did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll check it as soon as possible. Not really. I'm playing, experimenting with linear layout manager when I'm free. Actually I think it's doable. When I find solution I'll post here.

Comment: well, the superslim library has the ability to overlay the headers,, im not sure about the clicks though. I still need to implement it so I will let you know when i manage to do it.